# JQuery Mobile remove disc background

Tags: jquery-mobile

is there a way to remove the background disc (circle) from around and icon? the only reference for a disc I've found is below

```
background:                         rgba(0,0,0,.4) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
```

Comment: You might want to show some html there acctman or you are likely to get voted down and closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this to override the JQM css.

```
.ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield::after {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: url(http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/images/icons-18-white.png);    
}​​​​​
```

Comment: Should also add box-shadow: none; otherwise the circle border will show.

Answer (score 6):

If your using jquery mobile 1.4 use `class="ui-nodisc-icon"`

Comment: This is the best answer for version 1.4! Here's the documentation for reference: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/icons/#Removingthedisc

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.3.0, add class **ui-icon-nodisc**

Comment: Are you sure you are using 1.3.x? Check out the [docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/#Removingthediscandshadow)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came with this solution :

```
.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-       bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after {
background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
.az-nodisc {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Then apply the style as:

```
<a href="#" class="az-nodisc ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-nodisc-icon">test</a>
```